# How to find a general real solution to a third order non-homogeneous differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I am completely stuck with this non homogenous differential equation:

$x'''+(\alpha + \beta)x'' + (1+ \alpha\beta)x' = sin(2t) $

I have to show that the general real solution to aforementioned equation holds the form of

$x(t) = c_1+c_2e^{at}\cos(\omega t) + c_3e^{at}\sin(\omega t) + A\cos (2t) + B\sin (2t)$

and $a, \omega,$ A and B must have determined real parameters. I know I have to solve this by using the method of undetermined coefficients, but those $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are giving me very complicated solutions that I can't wrap my head around. Any solutions?

EDIT:

Due to possible confusion, I put up a link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ru6k.png) with the snippet of how the problem is formulated in my book.

Comment: first thing I would do is reduce the order by using $y(t)=x'(t)$

Answer (score 0):

Letting $A = a_1$ and $B = b_1$ (just for notation's sake):

You have 
$$x(t) = c1 + c2e^{at}cos(wt) + c3e^(at)sin(wt) + a_1 cos(2t) + b_1sin(2t)$$
Deriving three times, we can get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x'(t) &= \left(ac_3-c_2w\right)\mathrm{e}^{at}\sin\left(wt\right)\\
&+\left(c_3w+ac_2\right)\mathrm{e}^{at}\cos\left(wt\right)-2a_1\sin\left(2t\right)+2b_1\cos\left(2t\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x''(t) &=  \left(-c_3w^2-2ac_2w +  a^2c_3\right)\mathrm{e}^{at}\sin\left(wt\right) \\ &+ \left(-c_2w^2+2ac_3w+a^2c_2\right)\mathrm{e}^{at}\cos\left(wt\right)-4b_1\sin\left(2t\right)-4a_1\cos\left(2t\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x'''(t) &= \left(c_2w^3-3ac_3w^2-3a^2c_2w+a^3c_3\right)\mathrm{e}^{at}\sin\left(wt\right)\\ &+\left(-c_3w^3-3ac_2w^2+3a^2c_3w+a^3c_2\right)\mathrm{e}^{at}\cos\left(wt\right)+8a_1\sin\left(2t\right)-8b_1\cos\left(2t\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

**Now, just plug all three derivatives back in the equation to check if they satisfy the equation, i.e check if**
$$x'''(t)+(\alpha + \beta)x''(t) + (1+ \alpha\beta)x'(t) = sin(2t)$$

Comment: Sorry but I am confused. Why exactly do you differentiate the answer? Normally, you would write $x(t) = A \cos 2t + B \sin 2t$ and then differentiate it 3 times and plug it into the differential equation

Comment: Letting $A = a_1$ and $B = b_1$ (just for notation's sake)

Comment: also i think you mean by $A$ as $\alpha$ and $B$ as $\beta$

Comment: That's exactly not what I mean. I wrote the equations just as they are in the book, unless it mixes up $A$ as $\alpha$ and $B$ as $\beta$, which I doubt it does

Comment: Okay well you'd have to check if there exists constant $A,B$ that are functions of $\alpha,\beta$

Comment: So yes, normally you'd have to find constants $A$ and $B$ first, but when I try doing that, it just gives pretty complicated solutions. I tried Maple, but no luck. Am I not getting here something? Maybe I'm formulating the questions weirdly

Answer (score 0):

I'll post another approach as @Vasya suggests:

Let 
$$y = x'$$Then, you get
$$y''+(\alpha + \beta)y' + (1+ \alpha\beta)y = sin(2t)$$
Solve the homogenous part
$$y''+(\alpha + \beta)y' + (1+ \alpha\beta)y = 0$$
That is get the discriminant
\begin{equation}
 \Delta = b^2 - 4ac =(\alpha + \beta)^2 - 4 (1+ \alpha\beta)
 =
 \alpha^2 + 2\alpha\beta + \beta^2 - 4 - 4\alpha\beta
 =
 (\alpha - \beta)^2 - 4
\end{equation}
which is
\begin{equation}
 \Delta = (\alpha - \beta - 2)(\alpha - \beta + 2)
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
 y_h = k_1 e^{\frac{-(\alpha + \beta) - \sqrt{(\alpha - \beta - 2)(\alpha - \beta + 2)}}{2}t}
 +
 k_2 e^{\frac{-(\alpha + \beta) +\sqrt{(\alpha - \beta - 2)(\alpha - \beta + 2)}}{2}t}
\end{equation}
Now you need a particular solution of the differential equation $y_p$ which is under the form
\begin{equation}
 y_p(t) = A\cos(2t) + B\sin(2t)
\end{equation}
Just plug them up there to get $A$ and $B$ in terms of $\alpha,\beta$, then the solution is 
\begin{equation}
 y(t) = y_h(t) + y_p(t)
\end{equation}
that is
 \begin{equation}
  y_{\Delta > 0}(t) = k_1 e^{\frac{-(\alpha + \beta) - \sqrt{(\alpha - \beta - 2)(\alpha - \beta + 2)}}{2}t}
 +
 k_2 e^{\frac{-(\alpha + \beta) +\sqrt{(\alpha - \beta - 2)(\alpha - \beta + 2)}}{2}t} 
 +
 A\cos(2t) + B\sin(2t)
 \end{equation}
 If $\Delta > 0$, then we have the above form. If $\Delta < 0$ , then the above becomes 
  \begin{equation}
  y_{\Delta < 0}(t) = k_1 e^{\frac{-(\alpha + \beta) -i \sqrt{(\alpha - \beta - 2)(\alpha - \beta + 2)}}{2}t}
 +
 k_2 e^{\frac{-(\alpha + \beta) +i\sqrt{(\alpha - \beta - 2)(\alpha - \beta + 2)}}{2}t} 
 +
 A\cos(2t) + B\sin(2t)
 \end{equation}
 which could be written as 
  \begin{equation}
  y_{\Delta < 0}(t) = \frac{k_1}{2} e^{at}
  (\cos wt - i \sin wt) 
 +
 \frac{k_2}{2} e^{at}
 (\cos wt + i \sin wt) 
 +
 A\cos(2t) + B\sin(2t)
 \end{equation} 
 where 
 \begin{equation}
  w 
  =
  \frac{\sqrt{-(\alpha - \beta - 2)(\alpha - \beta + 2)}}{2}
 \end{equation}
 and
 \begin{equation}
  a  = \frac{-(\alpha + \beta)}{2}
 \end{equation}
 or even more you could factor the above as 
 \begin{equation}
   y_{\Delta < 0}(t) = c_1e^{at}
     \cos wt + c_2e^{at} \sin wt
     +
 A\cos(2t) + B\sin(2t) 
 \end{equation}
 where $c_1 = \frac{k_1+k_2}{2}$ and $c_2 = -\frac{k_1 - k_2}{2}$.
 If $\Delta = 0$, then we have
  If $\Delta > 0$, then we have the above form. If $\Delta < 0$ , then the above becomes 
  \begin{equation}
  y_{\Delta = 0}(t) = c_1 e^{\frac{-(\alpha + \beta)}{2}t}
 +
 k_2 te^{\frac{-(\alpha + \beta) }{2}t} 
 +
 A\cos(2t) + B\sin(2t)
 \end{equation}
You should work with all three cases, i'll show you how to work with one to get $x(t)$ back (assuming $\Delta < 0$)
\begin{equation}
 x(t) = \int y_{\Delta < 0}(t) \ dt
 =
 c_0
 +
 c_1 \int e^{at}
     \cos wt + c_2 \int e^{at} \sin wt
     +
  \int A\cos(2t) +  \int B\sin(2t) 
\end{equation}
Using integration by parts twice you can easily show that 
\begin{equation}
 \int e^{at}
     \cos wt
     =
 \dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{at}\left(w\sin\left(wt\right)+a\cos\left(wt\right)\right)}{w^2+a^2}  
\end{equation}
also
\begin{equation}
 \int e^{at}
     \sin wt
     =
\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{at}\left(a\sin\left(wt\right)-w\cos\left(wt\right)\right)}{w^2+a^2}+C
\end{equation}
Also 
\begin{equation}
 \int \cos 2t = \frac{1}{2} \sin t
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
 \int \sin 2t =- \frac{1}{2} \cos t 
\end{equation}
Plug everything back up and you'd get the form you're looking for.